# SelectedIndexChanged event is not firing when OwnerDrawFixed mode selected for Combobox in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I have combobox and changed DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed and handled DrawItem event, but now when i tried to change selectedIndex to -1 as there is no value in database for this. so SelectedIndexChanged is not working.

I have set `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`
`DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed`

Draw Item Method:

```
private void cmbDetTechnician_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         int index = e.Index >= 0 ? e.Index : 0;
         var brush = Brushes.Black;
         e.DrawBackground();
         e.Graphics.DrawString(lstTechnician[index].DisplayName.ToString(), e.Font, brush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
         e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Now i don't have value to Employee ID then combobox should be set to `SelectedIndex` to -1 but it is not working:

```
if(_EmployeeID == -1){cmbDetTechnician.SelectedIndex =  -1; } else { cmbDetTechnician.SelectedValue = _EmployeeID; }
```

I have also tried to handle SelectedIndexChanged of this combobox. but event is not raised after above statement.

```
private void cmbDetTechnician_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CustomMessageBox.Show("HI");
}
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong or any better suggestion.

Comment: Do not hide programming bugs with try/catch-em-all/do-nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the drawing, not the SelectedIndex...

```
if(e.Index >= 0)
{
    int index = e.Index;
    var brush = Brushes.Black;
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.Graphics.DrawString(lstTechnician[index].DisplayName.ToString(), e.Font, brush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
else
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Comment: In the ComboBox.DrawItem event, e.Index is ALWAYS >= 0, so your else clause is dead code. There is definitely a problem if I want to Draw a specific Item again After the DropDown list is drawn the first time. For example, if I change the SelectedItem, the new Item will be redrawn, but the previously SelectedItem will Not be redrawn; resulting in graphics artifacts

Comment: @gridtrak the index is -1 when the SelectedIndex for the combobox is set to -1...so not dead code.   You need a way to draw no selection.  The reason you have artifacts I think is because you are not drawing the background.  No artifacts that I can see with above code.